# How to store an inverted index in to binary file?

Tags: java, binary, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have a HashMap of terms which contains data of what page the word appeared, the word's frequency in the page, and their positions.

Ex: Word - [page number, word frequency in page, positions in page ]

```
cat [1, 3, 1, 2, 5 ], [2, 2, 2, 5 ]
dog [2, 2, 1, 7 ]
```

How would I store this info in a binary file that is easy to read back?

I made the following attempt:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);

        for(String word: invertedIndex.keySet()) {
            out.writeUTF(word);  // Write the word
            for(Entry entry: invertedIndex.get(word)) {  // Info for a page
                out.writeInt(entry.pageNum); // Write its page number
                out.writeInt(entry.wordFrequency); // Write its freq in that page

                for(int position: entry.positions) {
                    out.writeInt(position); // Write the positions
                }
            }
        }

        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.close();
```

Not sure if this is correct... Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks, turns out my problem is more on how to decode this rather strictly encode.

Comment: Why not just serialize the `Map`, i.e. use an `ObjectOutputStream`?

Comment: @Andreas This is for an assignment and was told "DO NOT simply write serialized java objects to disk". Is there a way to preserve this data structure in binary?

Comment: *"Is there a way to preserve this data structure?"*  Yea ... you write code.  You have written code.  What is your actual question?

Comment: May be your teacher is looking for you to [compress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) before you serialize ?

Comment: @StephenC - How do I write this data to a binary file that will allow me read back the data easily? Like [cat 1 3 1 2 5  2 2 2 5  dog 2 2 1 7]. How do I store this in a binary file where I read it and know certain bytes (?) is a string?

Comment: See my answer ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to preserve this data structure?

Yea.  Lots of ways.

Hint: Your attempted solution is a good start.

However a complete solution requires a corresponding method to read the data back.  And when you attempt to write a read method that corresponds to your write code, you will discover that there is a systemic problem.  For example, there is no easy way to figure out where one list of `int` values ends and the next one begins.

There are ways to solve that.  *Think about it*.  How can you write two lists one after another so that you know where one ends and the next begins?

Note: your use of `ByteArrayOutputStream` is unnecessary.  You can write directly to a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in a `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: More precisely: he can tell where the current list ends, but then he can't tell if another follows, or the next term.

Comment: Consider the case of a word appearing on multiple pages.

Comment: The list ends when there is a string and that is when the next entry begins. But I'm not too familiar with how this is stored in binary. Like I write a word to binary using: out.writeUTF(word); and the other things as out.writeInt(entry.pageNum); out.writeInt(entry.wordFrequency);. Is it stored in a way that's like:  String int int String int int int. So when I first read the binary I know these bytes are strings and these bytes are int?

Comment: I want you to think about the how to write 2 lists of ints.  Once you have figured that out, you can generalize / apply the solution here.

Comment: Testing won't work.  Using DataInput / DataOutput formatting, the bit / byte patterns cannot be reliably distinguished.  HOWEVER, there is a way that you don't have to test.  (In fact, there are two ways.)  What does a list consist of?  There are the elements ... and there is **something else**.

Comment: @StephenC Can I add a negative number as a delimiter each time the list ends? I'm a bit stumped on what that something else is. Edit: Nvm, I dont think a negative number bit would distinguish as it could be part of something else...

Comment: @Baikol Since you know up front how many entries are in the list, start by writing the count. Then the reader can read that count, and will know exactly how many values follow.

Comment: There are basically two ways to encode a list whose size is not known to the reader: 1) write the list size before the list elements, 2) use an "out of range" value to mark the end of list.  This works *independently of encoding*.  For example, if you use markers, then you might call `getInt` to read the next `int` and then test if the value you got is the marker value.

Comment: @Andreas The count is just the second (value word frequency in page) + 1 (the page number). How does that help me know how many bytes to read to know I've reached the end of a string? I know after the string ends it'll be an int and the second int will tell me how many ints follow after that. Are you guys suggesting I store the counts of the string size and read that to know how many bytes my string is?

Comment: @Baikol That will tell you how long the positions list is, but how do you know how many pages there are? That's what I was hinting when I said you don't know whether another positions list or a new term comes after...

Comment: There is no need store the string size explicitly because `writeUTF` does that for you.  Read the Javadoc!  Anyhow: we have given you LOTS of hints.  It is now time for you to start thinking for yourself.  Or just write the "reading" code and try to get it to work.

Comment: @StephenC Ok thanks, I think I have an idea. Btw you suggested FileOutputStream, how do I use that with DataOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream? If I wrap FileOutputStream with BufferedOutputStream, wouldnt I lose out on the writeUTF call?

Comment: No you wouldn't assuming that you do it like this: DataOutputStream ( BufferedOutputStream ( FileOutputStream ) ).  (NB: that is not Java code!)